# golang sqlite mattn import by downloading the source code

Tags: sqlite, go

so i want to apply encryption on database .db file in golang using sqlite3. but apparently it does not support it. so what im trying to do is downloading the sqlite3 driver and want to add encryption when opening the db file.

i also tried using sql-cipher, the encryption work but they dont have json_extract sql capability while i needed that query.

so my only choice are

1. implement encryption by using mattn package
2. use sql-cipher and implement json_extract in go but i fear that it will be much slower

so im leaning toward the first way but i have issue importing it. anyone have any idea?

thank you

[image: this is my directory and test.net/custom-sql-cipher is my go mod name]